# Generate a certain colorful triangle

Tags: graphics, generative-art

I want to get a colorful triangle like this:

[image: colored triangles]

I hope to get a triangle with **any number of layers**. This is my current method. Actually, I'm not very content with these *graph theory* functions, since I have to use `Quiet` to mute the error information.

```
pointPair = Subsets[{{0, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]}, {2, 0}}, {2}];
midPoint[{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}, n_] := 
 Transpose[{Subdivide[a, c, n], Subdivide[b, d, n]}]
layers = 8;(*Control the layers*)
poly = Polygon /@ 
  FindClique[
   Quiet[NearestNeighborGraph[
     Level[RegionIntersection @@@ 
       Subsets[Line /@ 
         Transpose /@ 
          MapAt[Reverse, 
           Subsets[midPoint[##, layers] & @@@ pointPair, {2}], {2, 
            2}], {2}], {3}]]], {3}, All];
Graphics[Transpose[{RandomColor[Length[poly]], poly}]]
```

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7360)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am late to see this question but here is a solution closely based on my answer to [Creating a Sierpinski gasket with the missing triangles filled in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7360/121).

```
tri[n_] :=
  Table[{2 j - i, Sqrt[3] i}, {i, 0, n}, {j, i, n}] // 
    Partition[Riffle @@ #, 3, 1] & /@ Partition[#, 2, 1] &
```

Example of use:

```
Map[{RandomColor[], Polygon@#} &, tri[5], {2}] // Graphics
```

[image]

---

### A different approach

For some reason I found this problem unusually interesting so that even after "solving" it I was thinking about it.  It occurred to me that the total number of triangles is $n^2$ therefore I wanted to make a function that could generate these from a call to `Array` rather than `Table`. (The latter permits non-rectangular indices as used in my first method.)

My method is to reflect the triangles that fall outside of target back inside.

[image]

```
fn[n_] := Array[fn, {n, n}]

fn[i_, j_] /; j > i := fn[j, i + 1, -1]

fn[x_, y_, s_: 1] :=
  { 2 x - y + {0, 1, 2}, Sqrt[3] {y, s + y, y} }\[Transpose] // Polygon

Map[{RandomColor[], #} &, fn[7], {2}] // Graphics
```

[image]

- Note: by design every triangle is generated separately which is not as efficient as my first approach which generates entire rows in one operation.

Keeping the coloration separate allows some interesting flexibility.  Coloring sequentially provides a pleasing effect due to the order of generation.

```
Module[{i = 0},
  Map[{ColorData["Rainbow"][i++/144], #} &, fn[12], {2}] // Graphics
]
```

[image]

Color based on the array coordinates:

```
Array[{Hue[##/400, #/7, #2/7], fn @ ##} &, {7, 7}] // Graphics
```

[image]

Comment: Impressive to your code.

Comment: @yode I am glad you like it. :-)

Comment: Both look good, but the latter is much slower...

Comment: @DPF Thank you.  I am not surprised regarding speed; the first one was written with efficiency in mind, while the second one is simply pursuing a particular idea.

Answer (score 14):

I guess something like this:

```
With[{n = 7},
     BlockRandom[SeedRandom["triangles"];
                 Graphics[Table[{RandomColor[],
                                 RegularPolygon[{Sqrt[3] (j + i - 1),
                                                 3 j + Boole[EvenQ[i]]}/2,
                                                {1, (-1)^i π/6}, 3]},
                                {i, 2 n - 1}, {j, n - Quotient[i, 2]}]]]]
```

[image: some colored triangles]

Answer (score 12):

This question is not a bit hard:

```
mat = {{1, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}};
draw[n_] := 
  Graphics[Table[{RandomColor[], 
       Triangle[{{i + n + 1 - #, j + n + 1 - #}, {i, j + 1}, {i + 1, 
           j}}.mat]}, {i, n}, {j, # - i}] & /@ {n, n + 1}];
draw[8]
```

Code is easy, check it by yourself~

Comment: small error: `{i, 8}` should be `{i, n}`

Comment: @m_goldberg thanks！

Comment: Here is a slight variation of your code: `draw[n_] := 
 Graphics[Table[{RandomColor[], 
      Triangle[{{i, j} + 1 - #, {i, j + 1}, {i + 1, j}}.mat]}, {i, n}, {j, 
      n + # - i}] & /@ {0, 1}]`.  Or using an additional `Table` iterator instead of `Map`:  `draw[n_] := 
 Graphics @ 
  Table[{RandomColor[], Triangle[{{i, j} - z, {i, j + 1}, {i + 1, j}}.mat]}, {z, -1,
     0}, {i, n}, {j, n + 1 + z - i}]`

Answer (score 8):

Anothor way by `NestList`

```
randomTriPlot[n_] := Module[{next},
  next[polys_] := 
   Join[Map[# + {-1, -Sqrt[3]} &, 
     polys, {2}], {MapAt[# - 2 Sqrt[3] &, 
      polys[[-1]], {1, 2}], # + {1, -Sqrt[3]} & /@ polys[[-1]]}];
  (*get coordinate of the next layer by translate this layer*)
  Flatten@
    Map[Polygon, 
     NestList[next, N@{{{0, 0}, {-1, -Sqrt[3]}, {1, -Sqrt[3]}}}, 
      n - 1], {2}] // Graphics[Thread[{RandomColor[Length@#], #}]] &
  ]
randomTriPlot[7]
```

Comment: 你是“无影冬瓜”么？感觉名字好像啊…

Comment: @Wjx Yes, you got it:)

Comment: Xie xie gua ge. :)

Answer (score 4):

Using the trick in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61807/125) to use `MeshFunctions` and `Dynamic` `MeshShading` with random colors:

```
coloredTriangles = ParametricPlot[{x, y Sqrt[3] Min[x, 2 - x]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 1}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {Sqrt[3] # + #2 &, #2 - Sqrt[3] # &, #2 &}, 
     Mesh -> # - 1, Exclusions -> None, ImageSize -> 200,
     MeshShading -> Dynamic@{{{RandomColor[], RandomColor[]}, {RandomColor[], 
              RandomColor[]}}}, Frame -> False, Axes -> False] &;
```

Examples:

```
Row[coloredTriangles /@ {3, 4, 6, 8}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Trick....... @kglr

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];

(* r1 splits a triangle into four parts using Midpoint functionality*)

r1 = Triangle[{a_, b_, c_}] :> Sequence[
    Triangle[{a, Midpoint[{a, c}], Midpoint[{a, b}]}]
    , Triangle[{b, Midpoint[{b, c}], Midpoint[{b, a}]}]
    , Triangle[{c, Midpoint[{c, a}], Midpoint[{c, b}]}]
    , Triangle[{Midpoint[{a, c}], Midpoint[{a, b}], Midpoint[{b, c}]}]
    ];

itri = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]}}];    
tris = First@#[[Length@# ;;]] &@NestList[# /. r1 &, {itri}, 3];
Graphics[{Riffle[RandomColor[Length@tris], tris]}]
```

[image]

---

**3D view**

```
itri = Triangle[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]}}];
SeedRandom[2];

r2 = Triangle[{{a1_, a2_}, {b1_, b2_}, {c1_, c2_}}] :> Triangle[{
     {a1, a2, Log[1/4, Area[Triangle[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}}]]]}
     , {b1, b2, 
      Log[1/4, Area[Triangle[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}}]]]}
     , {c1, c2, 
      Log[1/4, Area[Triangle[{{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}, {c1, c2}}]]]}
     }];

tris3 = NestList[# /. r1 &, {itri}, 3] /. r2 // Flatten;
tris3D = Riffle[RandomColor[Length@tris3], tris3];

Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], tris3D}
 , Axes -> True
 , AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}
 ]
```

[image]